# Connecting to TE M5600 bluetooth 4.0 pressure sensor

Tags: bluetooth

A similar question has been asked before , but I'm unsure how to add a follow up question ....

Essentially, I want to connect one of these M5600 sensors to a RPI to use with a python script of pressure logging .

All attempts so far to connect to my linux (ubuntu) development machine have also failed - my TPLink UB400 BT4.0 dongle sees the device but refuses to connect. I managed to get it to connect to another ble device using gatttool , so I'm sure the dongle is working ok.

Any assistance would be welcome

TIA

Bill

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What's your objective of asking this question?

Comment: I'm hoping one of the previous posters (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77578/connecnting-to-te-m5600-bluetooth-4-0-pressure-sensor) might be able to point me at a way of connecting the RPI without recompiling the rpi kernel (way beyond my ability!) . One poster implied that a particular usb adapter could help.

Comment: Ok. Good. Please add this comment as an **UPDATE** to the question. Maybe others could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, so to answer my question for the benefit of others:

Using the specified Laird USB BT900-US adapter configured with correct firmware and loaded with the precompiled smartZ basic program. The sensor can then be accessed via the ttyUSBx serial port with a 'gatttool' like app that is running on the adapter.

1 send "smartZ" to start the USB app.

2 wait for "-------->" prompt to ensure app is running

3 send "hcitool lecc 01xxxxxxxxxxxx" {01= BT900 type : xx = MAC address of device}

4 wait for "Connection handle hhhhhh" {hh =  con handle}

5 wait for "-------->-------->" prompt

6 send "gatttool –b 01xxxxxxxxxx  --char-read --handle=0x00000020 {x = MAC : 0x00000020 is data handle}

7 wait for "ConHandle:hhhhhhh Characteristic value/descriptor: B30979730F00F088F0FF6C346900 (\B3\tys\0F\00\F0\88\F0\FFl4i\00) {hh = connection handle from above : hex value is temperature and pressure readings as defined at the end of the software manual }

The above is a minimal set up. Your program should scan for devices with "hcitool lescan", parse the returned data to determine the device type and MAC , use "gatttool -b 01xxxxxxxxxxx --primary" and gatttool -b 01xxxxxxxxxxx --characteristics" to determine handle numbers by comparing to UUIDs.

Basically lots of string parsing !

(WHY! don't designers of these things have a non-verbose response version to make the process easier and more reliable????)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.